# Non-Retina images on a retina iPad

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, image, ipad

i'm developing an iOS app for iPad, i'm using normal images not @2x images so will this works in the new iPad? or it is must to include @2x images?
Any help is thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use normal images on the retina screens, but they will not look as crisp as the high resolution images.

Comment: @Abizem thanks for the reply,so if i get a new set of 2x images then say its dimension is obviously twise say i have background.png in 40x40 & background2x.png in 80x80 dimensions so now in my xib file i need to place a image view with 40x40 & in imageviews image property i need to mention 2x image name, Am i right?

Comment: If your image is 40x40 then you provide a normal image of that size and if you later add a retina image just double the dimensions and add a @2x to it - the resolution will be handled for you.